# In jsViews there is a `setProperty()` method. How do I do `removeProperty()`?

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

In the jsRender documentation there is a method `$.observable(object).setProperty()` but how do I remove a property from the object observably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a removeProperty() method. It is a recent addition to the API, so not yet in the documentation (to be added soon).

`$.observable(myObject).removeProperty("propertyName")`

Comment: Thank you Boris. jsRender is a critical part of all my projects - awesome plugin!